# Show if the region $u=\frac{1}{3}$ is (or not) a limit cycle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, dynamical-systems

I have the following diferential equation
$$
\left( \frac{du}{d\phi}\right)^2= 2\left(u + \frac{1}{6} \right)\left( u -
 \frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}  \,\, , \qquad (1)
$$
for the region wich has the solutions:
$$
u(\phi) = -\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\tanh^{2}\left(\frac{\phi+\phi_{0}}{2}\right) \,\, , \qquad (2)
$$
for $u < 1/3$ and making the susbstituion in the differential equation (1)
$$
u = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\tan^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\right) \,\, , \qquad (3)
$$
we get the following new equation
$$
\left( \frac{d\epsilon}{d\phi}\right)^{2} = \sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\right) \,\, . \qquad (4)
$$
Taking the following appropriate solution
$$
\phi = 2 \log \left(\tan \frac{1}{4} \epsilon\right) \,\, , \qquad (5)
$$
a substituing back this solution in eq. (3) we get, 
$$
u(\phi) = \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2e^{\phi}}{(e^{\phi}-1)^{2}} \,\, , \qquad (6)
$$
for $u > 1/3$.

Plotting these curves I can see that both of them tend asymptotically to $u = 1/3$. I have an intuition that $u = 1/3$ might be a limit cycle, to show this I'm trying to apply the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, but I'm having no insight about how to show this... Is there any way show this?

[image: Plot of the orbits. Here is plotted the variable $r := \frac{1}{u}$, so the value that is possible a limit cycle is $r = 3$.]

Comment: are you sure that your solution of the differential equation is correct?

Comment: Yeah, it was missing some intermediate steps, I've updated my question!

Comment: Sorry but (1) does not suffice to determine $u$ hence the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the constant function $u=\frac13$ satisfies this implicit ODE, this gives a closed orbit. As the sign of the derivative in the explicit form $\dfrac{du}{dϕ}=\pm (u-\frac13)\sqrt{u+\frac16}$ can take both variants, you have as many solutions moving away from that orbit as you have solutions moving toward that orbit.

Comment: I'm not sure about which derivative you are talking about.

Comment: $\frac{du}{dϕ}=\pm (u-\frac13)\sqrt{u+\frac16}$. Both sign variants are valid.

Comment: In what sense $u = \frac{1}{3}$ is a closed orbit?

Comment: @Evgeny : The plane curve given by this parametrization in polar coordinates, that is the circle with radius $r=1/u=3$, is the closed orbit. The parametrization with the angle is obviously a line, not closed. The question is about the curves in the diagram, not their parametrization.